# Undefined named 'context' while navigating

Tags: flutter, dart, screen, navigator

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'fruits_listing_card.dart';
import 'fruits_page.dart';

Map<String, Widget> fruits = {
  "banana": FruitsListingCards(
    fruitBGColor: 0xFFF8A8B5,
    fruitImagePath: 'images/fruits/banana.png',
    fruitName: 'Banana',
    fruitPrice: 'Rs. 105',
    fruitShortDescription: 'Ripe & Tasty',
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FruitsPage()),);
    },
  ),
}
```

// Second File

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class FruitsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Both the code are in different files.
FruitsListingCards is a widget that has a Gesture detector functionality. onTap is a parameter that takes function. 
I am using FruitsListingCards in the main file and whenever a user taps on it, should go to the FruitsPage screen. But the error is not letting me to do so. Any solution with proper explanantion will help me a lot.

EDIT:
For proper understanding of code, check my repo:
https://github.com/RaghavTheGreat1/fruits_delivery/tree/master/lib

Comment: Can you provide us with your entire code for these classes? It's important for us to be able to see how the classes work together. Pull your classes into a single file and post them here please.

Comment: @SupposedlySam https://github.com/RaghavTheGreat1/fruits_delivery/tree/master/lib

Comment: The code listed above is not present inside of your repo currently.

Comment: I believe you can probably just require `BuildContext context` as an argument to your `onTap` function. Then, where you call `onTap` you can pass in the context there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out the problem on omy own and it was easier than what other people had suggested me even if they haven't looked into my code committed in my GitHub repo.

The quick solution or fix was to add `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => fruitsPage));` inside the anonymous function of GestureDetector in FruitsListingCards and then returning fruitsPage(which is a dynamic variable that will take Class object as parameter).

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide context some how, so that it can connect the last screen and next screen.

You can wrap inside a function for that.

Following minimal code will help you more to understand.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {   
@override  
_DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState(); 
}

class FruitsPage extends StatelessWidget {   
final Function call;   
FruitsPage({this.call});   
@override   
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("press"),
            onPressed: call,
          ),
        );   
} 
}

    class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {   
    @override   
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: Text("FruiysPage"),
                ),
              ),
            );   
} 
}




    callme(context) {   
Map<String, Widget> fruits = {
        "banana": FruitsPage(
          call: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewPage()),
            );
          },
        )   
};   
return fruits; 
}
```

Comment: using context flutter can recognise screens, so you need context in navigation because using that flutter will understand from which screen to screen screen you want to navigate. In conclusion, to pass context we have to do that thing. Accept my answer if it help you.

Comment: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: visible

It failed when I debugged

Comment: My situation is more complex than your code expresses, I think. 
I am using the key of fruits dictionary to call the FruitsListingCards one by one in the main. Now if I wrap the dictionary with a function, then how will I extract the FruitsListingCards?

Comment: Please go through my repo and check the mechanism. If possible, please fork it and pull issue so that I can better understand.. Sorry for the trouble, but I am still learning.